# add http header to zeppelin server rest api

Tags: http, configuration, http-headers, apache-zeppelin

i integrate with zeppelin on my application , the rest api's return to me the following error :

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/notebook/2CBB836VW/permissions. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

after searching i found that i must include the header in the server

```
"X-ACCESS_TOKEN", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Authorization", "Origin", "x-requested-with", "Content-Type", "Content-Range", "Content-Disposition", "Content-Description"
```

where can i found the configuration  file and add this on zeppelin .